# BoxLayout doesn't resize when adding widget dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have an issue I can't resolve by myself:

What I have in Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class Dossier(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, nom_, **kwargs):
        super(Dossier, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 2
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = self.minimum_height
        self.nom = nom_

        self.ids.TB.text = nom_

    def clic(self):
        temp = Dossier(str(self.nom) + "\\sous-dossier")
        self.ids.SD.add_widget(temp)


class testApp(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, nom_, **kwargs):
        super(testApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 2
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.height = self.minimum_height
        self.nom = nom_

        self.add_widget(Dossier(nom_))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return testApp('test')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

What I have in kv file:

```
<Dossier>:

    ToggleButton:

        id: TB
        size_hint_y : None
        height: 25
        halign : 'left'
        valign : 'center'
        on_press: root.clic()
    
    BoxLayout:

        id: SD
        orientation : 'vertical'
        spacing : 2
        size_hint_y : None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

When I click on the ToggleButton "TB", here is what I get:

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: after]

The object "Dossier" I add contain just a ToggleButton with a height of 25 and an empty (at the moment of creation) BoxLayout. With a spacing of 2, the height of the instance of "Dossier" (which inherit of BoxLayout) is 27.

But when I add it to the empty BoxLayout of my "root" "Dossier", The BoxLayout doesn't change it's size and the child object is draw on top of the parent.

I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'm not a native English Speaker.

Answer (score 0):

## Adding widget - missing size

When adding widget, specify the size of the widget e.g. `size_hint_y=None, height=40`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


Builder.load_string("""
<Dossier>:

    ToggleButton:

        id: TB
        text: 'Dossier'
        size_hint_y : None
        size : (1,25)
        halign : 'left'
        valign : 'center'

    BoxLayout:

        id: SD
        orientation : 'vertical'
        spacing : 2
        size_hint_y : None
        height: self.minimum_height
""")


class Dossier(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, nom_, **kwargs):
        super(Dossier, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        self.spacing = 2
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.size = (485, 0)
        self.nom = nom_

        self.ids.TB.text = nom_
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.simulation_add_widgets(), 5)

    def simulation_add_widgets(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.ids.SD.add_widget(Button(text="btn "+str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Dossier('1')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: This works perfectly and it was what I was doing, but I forgot to mention that the object I add to "SD" is another object "Dossier". and when I do that, your example does'nt work anymore. I will Edit my firest question with your example modified.

Comment: In your latest example, the BoxLayout will not resize / grow because each box is at its minimum height and it is stacked on top each other.

Comment: but when I add a widget, the "minimum_height" doesn't change, but with a Button instead of an object "Dossier", it does change the height. 
How can I achieve what I try to do?